# VBA Copy And Paste Only Copying 1st Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I hope you are all well.

I am trying to use the below code to add orders of different products together. but only products with a value greater than 0 in column D. Unfortunately though the code for some reason is only copying the first row of the range, even though there are other rows which meet the criteria. can anyone help?

```
Sub ADDTOORDERS()
Dim Sh As Worksheet, C As Worksheet, Last As Long
Set Sh = Sheets("Menu")
Set C = Sheets("LensOrder")
With Sh
Last = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("B7:D" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    C.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Sheets("Menu").Range("C3").Select
   .Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking field 3 if you want D?

Comment: Such An Idiot Thank You. @SJR can I ask though I am Running The macro but it always copy the first row of the range even though it doesnt meet the criteria why would that be ?

Comment: Easily done! Do you mean it always copies row 7 or 8? AF assumes a header row so it will copy the top row. If you don't have any headings add a header row and offset your copied range by 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Made only 1 change. check this. last row thing.

```
Sub ADDTOORDERS()
Dim Sh As Worksheet, C As Worksheet, Last As Long
Set Sh = Sheets("Menu")
Set C = Sheets("LensOrder")
With Sh

.Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
Last = .range("B500000").end(xlup).row 
.Range("B7:D" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
C.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Sheets("Menu").Range("C3").Select
.Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: I have gone through it Praveen and feel that it is something really obvious but I cant see the error. I know its something like that I am telling it to copy the first row irregardless of the value but I cant see where I am doing it.

Comment: I run your one and it is still copying that first row b7 even though it has no value

Comment: Give me the raw data, I will write simplest code for you... Just sample 2 row data. post here in comments.

Comment: Column B                                                                Column C              Col D
PROTECT PLATINUM TRIAL  8.4 -00.25 (5) TDIAG1BK84-0025       1
PROTECT PLATINUM TRIAL  8.4 -00.50 (5) TDIAG1BK84-0050       0
PROTECT PLATINUM TRIAL  8.4 -00.75 (5) TDIAG1BK84-0075       12

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your are trying to copy the resulting range, however that range has several areas, thus it's only copying the first area.
One of the methods to work in this situation is to pass the resulted range into an array then to post the array into the desired range.

This solution assumes the header is at row 6

Try the code below:

```
Option Base 1 'This must be at the top of the module

Sub Add_Orders()
Dim wshSrc As Worksheet, wshTrg As Worksheet
Dim rCpy As Range, aCpy() As Variant
Dim rArea As Range, rRow As Range
Dim lRowLst As Long, lRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wshSrc = .Worksheets("Menu")
        Set wshTrg = .Worksheets("LensOrder")
    End With

    lRowLst = wshSrc.Cells(wshSrc.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
''    With wshSrc.Range("B7:D" & lRowLst) 'The filter should always include the header - Replacing this line       
    With wshSrc.Range("B6:D" & lRowLst) 'With this line
        ReDim Preserve aCpy(.Rows.Count)
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
        Set rCpy = .Rows(1).Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Use the offset and resize to exclude the header 
    End With

    For Each rArea In rCpy.Areas
        For Each rRow In rArea.Rows
            lRow = 1 + lRow
            aCpy(lRow) = rRow.Value2
    Next: Next
    ReDim Preserve aCpy(lRow)
    aCpy = WorksheetFunction.Index(aCpy, 0, 0)

    With wshTrg.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Cells(1).Resize(UBound(aCpy), UBound(aCpy, 2)).Value = aCpy
    End With

    End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx), 
[Option keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278518(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx),

[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx),

Comment: Thank you so much. :) It is offering me a Run Time Error 13 Mismatch when I try and run the Code??

Comment: I tested and it was ok, let me know in which line?

Comment: Ok sorry, just missed to include this line when copying from my module. `    Option Base 1 'This must be at the top of the module` Try now

Comment: It is still copying row B7

Comment: Before it was copying only row 7, now It's copying everything resulting from the filter including row 7. It's that correct. Now, It's row 7 the header? I'm assuming the header is at 6. Pls confirm the header is at 7, and everything else is copied, and I'll do the change...

Comment: 6 is the Header and everything below is the Order

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ready, suggest to always state the range of your data and if it has header... please try and let me know...

Comment: Then pls accept the answer and help to keep the site updated